# Fill variable with text of a .txt file at an FTP server in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I think my question sounds kinda stupid but I'm pretty new to python programming.

I just want to have a text variable which gets a string from a .txt file at an FTP server.

So in conclusion: There is a .txt File stored at an FTP server and I want to have the content of this file stored in an variable...

This is what I have so far... Can anybody help me? I use Python 3.6.3 :) thanks in advance!

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('1bk2t.ddns.net')
ftp.login(user='User', passwd = 'Password')

ftp.cwd('/path/')

filename = 'filename.txt'

ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
ftp.quit()

var = localfile.read
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download a text file contents to memory, without using any temporary file, use [`FTP.retrlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) like:

```
contents = ""
def collectLines(s):
    global contents
    contents += s + "\n"

ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, collectLines)
```

---

Or use an array:

```
lines = []
ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename, lines.append)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `StringIO` as buffer for `retrlines`  `RETR`:

```
import io

with io.StringIO() as buffer_io:
    ftp.retrlines(f'RETR {filename}', buffer_io.write)
    content = buffer_io.getvalue()
```

Comment: This way you loose the EOLs.

Comment: Yes, but some times it does not matter, for example for files like JSON/XML/HTML.

Comment: OK, but you should at least mention that in your answer. And even in XML/HTML *some* new lines matter.